# Gravatar does not display, how to correct?

Tags: support, user-accounts

If this is not the correct place to ask this question please move.  I searched and did not find any answers.

When I created my account I used the openid associated with my google acct.  I have images associated with that email in the gravatar system but they do not show on the site.  Is this a known problem?  Noob mistake?

I dislike the quilt square and would like to see my own ugly mug up there!

Thanks

MM/RC

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great feature on the Gravatar website](http://en.gravatar.com/site/check) to check to verify that your Gravatar is working.  I put your email address through the check and figured out the problem immediately.

For some reason, your Gravatar is X-rated:

[image: RealityCramp's Gravatar]

To fix this, log in to the Gravatar site and go to your profile.  When you hover the mouse over your headshot, you'll see the rating and a big red X show up just to the right:

[image: Gravatar Edit Screen]

Click on this rating and you'll be able to specify what your image is rated.  Since yours is just a headshot, I'd suggest a G-rating.  Then it should show up here (and everywhere else) just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The gravatar is [linked to the e-mail address you provide *in your profile on this site*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar). So go to [your user page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/514) (on the parent site, not on meta), click the *edit* link, and check your e-mail address there.

This site is part of a network of Stack Exchange sites. Because of historical reasons, most questions about the workings of sites in the network are answered at [the Stack Overflow meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I have checked the edit link.  Many many times.  All seems well and my pic shows in gravatar.  I will check the stack overflow meta site for help.